# Natural definitions of families of subgraphs

Tags: graph-theory, definition, formal-languages

[Cluster analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis) is a vibrant area of applied mathematics, "used in many fields, including machine learning, pattern recognition, image analysis, information retrieval, and bioinformatics". A subfield of cluster analysis of special mathematical interest - because of its clear-cut underlying definitions - is [graph clustering](https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/mlsurveys/13.pdf).

Graph clustering has also some philosophical impact, e.g. in the context of [logical atomism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_atomism) and [logical constructions](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logical-construction/) – both tracing back to B. Russell – or in R. Dipert's [The World as Graph](http://philpapers.org/rec/DIPTMS).

From [Wikipedia's cluster analysis entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis#Clusters_and_clusterings):

> a **clique**, i.e., a subset of nodes in a graph such that every two nodes
>   in the subset are connected by an edge can be considered as a
>   prototypical form of cluster. Relaxations of the complete connectivity requirement (a fraction of the edges can be missing) are known as quasi-cliques.

A completely different kind of graph clusters are the **orbits** of the automorphism  group of a graph $G$, which are not necessarily connected but contain similar (in fact: structurally identical) objects.

Both cliques and orbits seem to me prototypical "natural definitions" of families of subgraphs.

The above mentioned relaxations - there is an infinitude of them - usually depend on arbitrary numerical parameters and don't feel so natural, at least when the parameters are not natural in a sense.

Comparably, a definition of "*n*-cliques" using not immediate but intermediate connectivity - eg. by replacing "connected by an edge (= 1-path)" by "connected by an *n*-path" in the definition above - would not feel as natural as the "immediate" definition.

But it is hard to *formalize* this intuitive feeling of "naturality" which comprises among others:

- no arbitrary numerical parameters
- no arbitrary reference to singled-out (named) objects
- no unnecessary complifications of otherwise simple definitions

My question is:

> What attempts to define "natural definitions" are there, especially
>   with respect to families of subgraphs of arbitrary graphs? Is it
>   possible at all?

Answer (score 1):

I guess somehow we should rule out spurious ways to depend on parameter, such as

> "a graph is *$k$-cliqueish* if either $k=1$ and the graph is connected,
>   or $k\ge 2$ and the graph has a clique of size $k$".

Here is attempt (not constructive and not really canonical). Fix a first-order language $L$ containing some basic arithmetic so we can use parameters from $\mathbb N$.

**Definition 1.** For an $L$-definable function $f$ with domain $\mathbb N$, define the *complexity* $C(f)$ to be the shortest definition of $f$ in $L$.

**Definition 2.** For functions $f^*$ and $f$ with domain $\mathbb N$, we say that $f$ is an *improvement* of $f^*$ if $C(f)\le C(f^*)$, and for all but finitely many $n$, $f(n)=f^*(n)$.

**Definition 3.** A set $S$ *depends on a parameter* if there exists an injective $f$ with domain $\mathbb N$, such that for all improvements $g$ of $f$, there is an $n$ with $f(n)=g(n)=S$. In this case we say the value of the parameter can be $n$.

**Theorem(?)** The collection $S$ of graphs having a clique of size 5 does depend on a parameter (which can have the value 5), since a natural definition of "*clique of size $k$*" cannot be shortened and modified in such a way as to still be correct for almost all $k$, and at the same time remove $S$ from the range.